# Rails - how to persist instance variables between controller methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instance-variables

I'm learning rails, and creating a simple question/answer app to test some of the concepts I've been introduced to. I used generate scaffold to create two model classes - Question and User.

The questions table consists of a question_number (int), question_text (string) and answer_text (string).

The users table has a uid (string), name (string) and current_question (int)

I then created a controller called gateway. I have the app working now where a user can go to the main page passing their UID as a parameter (eventually will be passed by a login function) and the app will display the question they are currently working on by grabbing the question_number which matches the user's current_question. Great.

I then created an answer method in the gateway controller. This method takes an answer the user types into a form and compares it to the answer in the database, redirecting the user to different pages depending on if the answer was right or wrong.

My issue - I set instance variables in the index method to set the current user and current question - but these do not persist to my answer method. What is the Rails best practice here? Do I:

1) Pass these as parameters to the answer method through the form, just like I pass the answer (seems inefficient when I've already created the instance vars in the controller, and now pass them back...)
2) Store these as vars in the session?
3) Store these in Flash?
4) Just look them up again in the answer method (don't like repeating code, and 2 calls for same info seems wasteful)

Am I even using the right structure for this app? What would you do in this instance, where you want to grab an attribute of a user (their current authorized question) and use it several times to query another part of the database (step 1 - get question matching user's authorized question, step 2 - check that answer user inputs is correct, step 3 - increment the user's auth question counter)

### more info, @wukerplank

No plugins for session handling. Basically, my flow goes like this:

1. "login" user (no login logic in this little test app, so I just pass the uid as a param in the URL)
2. The gateway controller gets the user's current question with @question = Question.where(:question_number => @user.current_question).first
3. User is displayed the question text and a form to enter answer
4. Submit button calls my :answer action and passes the answer string
5. Here is where I'd love to just call @question again, but can't because it is not persisted. So I either have to repeat step 2, or find a place to store the data I need to reference again. I'm assuming the DRY principles of Rails would advise against repeating Step 2, so I'm wondering where/how the best way to store these (and other variables I may need) are
   Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like storing it in a session would be appropriate, depending on how much security you want.

In rails3 the session is actually stored in the cookie itself and has limited size.
If the variables are large objects then create a table in the database and just store the id in the session and look it up each time.

Alternatively you could use memcached or equivalent to store the session and then the cookie just stores a session ID.

Comment: Right now, I wouldn't need much space (I think it's a 4K limit, right?). However, given the space limitation and the security aspects (anyone can read the cookie, right?) do most Rails devs just go right to memcached/etc... to accomplish this?

Comment: If your @question will fit in the cookie then store it there. Of course the user will be able to see it in the cookie, but the cookie is obfuscated (not well), and has a checksum to avoid modification, but again not good security. I'd say most people would store the data in the sessions table in a database and simply store the id in the cookie. If you were to use a nosql storage (like memcached) it would be faster in the long run if you are concerned about performance. If you were to use a ruby cache store you could store @question directly without marshalling it.

Comment: Security is always an issue with sessions, whether you store the actual data or just a sessionid. Unless you use https the sessionid is visible to anyone and session stealing/highjacking is definitely a concern. Mitigation of session highjacking is a whole new topic :)

Answer (score 0):

I probably misunderstand your question, but the usual procedure would be:

- Log in the user
- store his ID in the session
- reload the user with every request from the DB via his ID in the session
- store relevant information (progress in quiz etc.) in the user table

Do you use a plugin for the session handling (Devise, Authlogic, etc.)?